# How do I display the values ​on the google chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to show the values ​​in the graph lines, as in the image, but found nothing in the documentation about it.
This value is shown only when I hover over the point on the graph line. I want the values ​​to be shown on the chart without having to hover over.
How do I display the values ​​on the google chart?
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your values are showing between 40 and 45 and your value is 42, so not sure what you want to achieve here because the graph seems to show the correct values. If you want it where you point the arrow, subtract 10 of your value and it'll be between 30 and 35.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: you will need to use an annotation column, see [labeling columns](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#labeling-columns) -- however, it appears you are using a _material_ chart (`google.charts.Line`) which does not support annotations, will need to use a _classic_ chart (`google.visualization.LineChart`)